# Find $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^3+\ln x+5}{5x^3+e^{-x}+\sin x}$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^3+\ln x+5}{5x^3+e^{-x}+\sin x}$

Studying L’hopital’s rule but cannot find the limit of this equation. I even put it in a calculator of limits and couldn’t get an answer.

Is there something tricky about this equations’ limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3+\log x+5}{5x^3+e^{-x}+\sin x}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{\log x}{x^3}+\frac5{x^3}}{5+\frac1{x^3e^x}+\frac{\sin x}{x^3}}\\&=\frac{1+0+0}{5+0+0}.\end{align}

Comment: It was easier than I expected. I’m sorry for not putting more effort in trying to solve it, as the calculator said it didn’t had an answer, I hesitated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Divide both numerator and denominator by $x^3$, then calculate the limit of each term when $x\to\infty$